# Wagmi can't read function: Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=true, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, react, ens, wagmi

***Hello everyone***,

I use *wagmi* with *rainbowkit* and I wanna check wallet address status with function "isApprovedForAll" response will be **true** or **false**, but I got undefined and error everytime same.

- new Ethereum Name Service address: [0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e#code)
- old Ethereum Name Service address: [0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85#code)

**information source about address: [Guide for DApp Developers](https://docs.ens.domains/ens-migration-february-2020/guide-for-dapp-developers#wallets-libraries-and-dapps-that-resolve-names)**

Code:

```
  const { address } = useAccount();
  const contractRead = useContractRead({
    address: ensContractAddress,
    functionName: 'isApprovedForAll',
    abi: ENSAbi,
    args: [address, true],
    chainId: goerli.id,
  });
```

this code must return for me ONLY **TRUE** or **FALSE** value.

Version:

```
@rainbow-me/rainbowkit: ^0.7.3
wagmi: ^0.7.5
```

Error:

```
ContractMethodDoesNotExistError: Function "isApprovedForAll" on contract 
"0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e" does not exist. 
Etherscan: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e#readContract
```

then I use old address: **0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85**
I got error:

```
Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=true, 
code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0
```

few fun fact:

- I checked and changed json abi.
- Wallet is connected.
- checked get information in [goerli.etherscan.io old contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x57f1887a8bf19b14fc0df6fd9b2acc9af147ea85#readContract) and [goerli.etherscan.io new contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e#readContract) not working here same.

[image: goerli.etherscan.io ENS contract result screenshot]

**Any ideas?
*Thank you***

Docs:

- [wagmi useContractRead docs](https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractRead)
- [ENS docs general](https://docs.ens.domains/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!.

*isApprovedForAll()* is a nft api
and I used bad function signature, becouse will be (address, address), but not (address, bool).
More information about registry api [here](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/ens)

Answer (score 0):

Wagmi is nice for small dapps but they hooks are lame

Comment: Can you recommend better? thanks

Comment: Using ethers to your send and call functions. Write it yourself.

Comment: you offer write almost everything from zero? :D It's sound not good, becouse it waste time